# How can I access my node which has name as the current user's name in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current code and it keeps creating a new node inside "Student"

```
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()..getReference("Student")
        var userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid

        val exmdata = examdata(stud_city, stud_centre, stud_slot, stud_examdate)
        if (userId != null) {
            dbRef.child(userId!!).child(stud_centre).setValue(exmdata)
```

This is what I want :
[image: The result I need]

This is the result I am getting :
[image: The result I am getting]

Comment: Can you please show what exactly you have under the `test` node?

Answer (score 0):

to get the result you are asking for, try to structure the data the same way you want it.

**example** :

```
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()..getReference("Student")
        var userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
         if (userId != null) {
            dbRef.child(userId!!).child("test01").setValue(exmdata)
```